# Multiple subdomain in iis7

Tags: tomcat, iis-7, subdomain

I have an app server running in tomcat 8080 port. Now, I need to configure multiple subdomain (like abc.mydomain.com, xyz.mydomain.com, 123.mydomain.com) pointing to the single app http://mydomin.com:8080/ through iis7. Is it possible? If yes, can you please guide me.

Thanks,
Herwin Rayen

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps given bellow ..
1. create subdomain and point to same server as domain . 
2. bind all the subdomain and domain to same site .right click on website and press binding in IIS . Add subdomian there .